# SBT task to copy debian file to other folder

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How to write a sbt custom task to copy debian file from `/target/scala-2.11/` folder to other folder ex: `/deploy/be` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
lazy val copyTask = taskKey[Unit]("copyDeb")    

copyTask := {
  val deb = (packageBin in Debian).value
  val destinationPath = file("deploy/be/").toPath
  java.nio.file.Files.copy(deb.toPath, destinationPath)
}
```